# How do I turn off the WPF XCeed DataGridControl alway selecting the first cell when the datagrid gets focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xceed

I have several WPF XCeed DataGrids defined.

Whenever a DataGrid gets focus, the 1st cell of the DataGrid is highlighted.
I would like to turn off this behavior as I am handling my own selection for these grids.

**Here is the XAML definition of the DataGrid:**

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl 
  x:Name="ReEnrollmentStepsDetailsGrid" 
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
  AutoCreateColumns="False" 
  SelectionMode="Extended"
  SelectionUnit="Cell"
  AllowDrag="True"
  AllowSearch="True"
  ReadOnly="True"  
  SelectionChanged="SampleGrid_SelectionChanged"
  Style="{StaticResource SampleGridStyle}"
  ItemContainerStyle ="{StaticResource SampleGridRowStyle}"
```

**After reading several posts, I tried adding the following attribute to my XAML definition.**

```
SynchronizeCurrent="False"
```

That attribute doesn't seem to have any effect. I still get the same results.

How do I disable this (what appears to be) default behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using adding some code behind for the Loaded event.

GridControl xaml:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl 
     ...
     Loaded="DataGridControl_Loaded">
```

c# code begin:

```
private void DataGridControl_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DataGridControl dg)
    {
        dg.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```